# checking proxy type in .net

Tags: .net, winforms, proxy

can anyone help me with code that check a proxy type in .net? so it i put a proxy information in a textbox, it will return the proxy type

there are about 4-5 types

```
Transparent, Anonymous, Elite, Anonymouse + Elite
```

it has something to do with the headers returned, here are some headers

```
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
HTTP_VIA
```

EDIT

there are about 5 categories of proxies

```
UNKNOWN_PROXY
DEAD_PROXY
HTTP_PROXY
SOCKS4_PROXY
SOCKS5_PROXY
```

The one am interested in is HTTP_PROXY. 
when you make a request via a proxy to google or any site, the headers returned somehow as i have heard also returns the type of proxy that is being used

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. What kind of proxy are you talking about? What exactly do you want to do with them? Who returns the headers to you?

Comment: i have added some more information

Comment: But what do you want to do with those proxy types? Find out if your computer is using one?

Comment: i need to know the type of proxy i am using, if it is ananymous, transparent etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you must setup a webserver (accessible by the proxy server)
your winform application send a http request to an web application deployed on that webserver via the proxy
the true request to your webserver will be send by the proxy server, you can check the header and see the IP you found is of your client or the proxy server and send back the type of the proxy.